# Lusitanian oauth set session from database key

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, laravel, oauth

I'm using https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel which is built on https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib.
I can get the extension to log me in and it sets its own session. I can retrieve the tokens and I save them in a database. How can I set a twitter and facebook oauth session from the tokens stored in my database?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's very easy

for facebook use

```
$token = new \OAuth\OAuth2\Token\StdOAuth2Token;
$token->setAccessToken(token_from_db);
//generate a Storage instance (using session here but could be anything else)
$storage = new \OAuth\Common\Storage\Session;
$storage->storeAccessToken('Facebook', $token);
$fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );
$result = json_decode($fb->request('/me'), true);
```

for twitter use like this

```
$token = new \OAuth\OAuth1\Token\StdOAuth1Token;
$token->setAccessToken('');
$token->setAccessTokenSecret(');

//generate a Storage instance (using session here but could be anything else)
$storage = new \OAuth\Common\Storage\Session;
$storage->storeAccessToken('Twitter', $token);
```